# Android Wear - Keeping track of the latest GooglePLayServices version for most wear models

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

Where can I check which is the latest GooglePlayServices version for the latest update of each watch?

I need to know this so that I can know when to increase my google play services version on my wear app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google only releases the SDKs associated with a new release when Google Play services has hit 100% of connected devices. For Android Wear devices, the upgrade happens as part of the rollout to an updated [Android Wear companion app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app) in which they also wait for that to hit 100%. Therefore you can always use the latest SDK.

Comment: I believe that is not true. There are some watches that are yet to receive the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can check installed version via terminal.

$ adb -s "specific device" shell

$ pm dump com.google.android.gms|grep version

My Moto 360 still has 7.8.99.